# Google Cloud Vision API Object Localization - number of recognized objects

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the following python code to detect License Plates with Cloud Vision API.

```
response = client.annotate_image({
    'image': {'source': {'image_uri': uri}},
    'features': [
        {'max_results': 1000, 'type_': vision.Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION},
        {'max_results': 1000, 'type_': vision.Feature.Type.OBJECT_LOCALIZATION},
    ],
})    

lo_annotations = response.localized_object_annotations
for obj in lo_annotations:
    print('\n{} (confidence: {})'.format(obj.name, obj.score))
    print('Normalized bounding polygon vertices: ')
    
    for vertex in obj.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices:
        print(' - ({}, {})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y))
```

If i use an image showing more cars, buildings, persons etc. I get about 4-7 objects recognized. The recognized objects are the bigger ones in the scene like "Car", "Car", "Building", "Building", "Person"

If I snip out just one car from this image and do the Object Localization with this new image I get objects like "Car", "Tire", "Tire", "License plate" which is perfect - because the plate gets recogized and listed.

So it seems the Object Localization algorithm picks out some prominent objects from the image and ignores smaller or less prominent objects.

But in my case I need to localize all license plates in the image. Is there a way to get the used Model to list all license plates in the image or more objects than just the most prominent ones?

Otherwise what would then be the right approach to get all plates out of an image - do I have to train a custom model?

Answer (score 0):

Vision API is a pre-trained image detection service provided by Google that could perform basic image detection like detecting of text, objects, etc. hence the observation you have mentioned about the API where it usually detects prominent objects in the image.

What I could suggest is, if the objects in your images usually appear in a specific area in the image (eg. objects appear at the lower half) you can pre-process the image by cropping it using [python libraries like PIL and OpenCV](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/crop-an-image-in-python) before using Vision API to detect license plates. Or detect the objects, get the coordinates per object, use coordinates as input to crop specific objects then use Vision API to detect license plates.

And also as you have mentioned, as an alternative you can always create a custom model to detect license plates if you are not satisfied with the results of Vision API. With a custom model, you have more freedom on how to tweak the model to increase the accuracy to detect license plates.